# JQuery tools overlay opens at the top of page instead of overlaying in IE, works fine in FF/Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Here is the sandbox version of my site:

http://truxmapper.appspot.com/

To reproduce the error, hover over to the toolbar and go to Support --> FAQ.  In Chrome/FF, this will work as expected.  In IE, the background image will quickly move to the center of the page, but when its time to insert the div over the background image, its inserted on top of the page rather than the center of the page.  The plugin example ( http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/apple.html ) works fine in IE, so i know it ought to be possible.

I've tried messing around with the div placement on the html and with the css to no avail.  Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Thanks!